# Transition React Navigation header background colour

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, mobile

I'm using this plugin for React Native navigation: https://reactnavigation.org/

I have two screens, one of them is light, one of them is dark. The header of the navigation on the first screen is light, on the other it switches to dark. But it switches header colour with no transition which is quite ugly. Any built-in option or hack to give the background colour switch a transition?

Here are my settings for switching the colours:

`` static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `Chat with ${navigation.state.params.character.characterName}`,
    headerTitleStyle: {
      color: colors.lightGrey
    },
    headerTintColor: colors.lightGrey,
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: colors.grey,
      shadowColor: 'transparent',
      borderBottomColor: colors.lighterGrey,
      borderBottomWidth: 0.5
    }
  }); ``

Answer (score -2):

i think better for you to make transition via css and just switch the classes for element

```
    .main-class-for-element{
     transition:background 0.3s linear;
    }
    .light-el{
      background:white;
    }
    .dark-el{
    background:black;
    }
```

Comment: This is React Native, CSS transitions do not exist